# xcode: disable atomic save

Tags: xcode, macos

Xcode appears to save files atomically when you save. This seems best practice but when you are listening for file changes atomic saves can dodge a kevent file status change. Im using a library called vdkqueue that listens for file changes. This will work successfully when a make a save on the target file using textedit and sublime text. However when I save this file using xcode the notifcation will not fire. This is due to xcode making atomic saves so a temp file is made on save and the link to the file is lost. Is there any way of disabling atomic save in xcode, or even a mac wide setting would suffice.

Comment: No @Zaph, I think he wants to detect when the Xcode IDE *saves* a file.  His VDKQueue library works fine with TextEdit & Sublime Text, but not Xcode.

Comment: Thats right @MichaelDautermann, I just wondered if there was someway of turning off atomic saves.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @zaph to elaborate more Ive just updated my question.

Comment: Maybe try locking the file.

Comment: hmm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are observing a file, that might not work (because the file you are observing is never actually modified). Observing the containing directory should work reliably.

Comment: so if i save a file within the containing directory, watching the containing folder could trigger an event?